# node.js equivalent of PHP if-else display html content

Tags: php, node.js

On PHP I have a session for logged in users, and if I want to display content for logged in users only I make a simple redirecting script:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']){
    header('Location: /login.php');
} else {
    // page content here
}
```

How do you do that in node?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: Are you talking about this kind of stuff:
```<?php
if(condition)
{
?> 
<html stuff/>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
Other html stuff
<?php
}
?>```

Comment: try to use middleware in node

Comment: yes dGRAMOP. Also, thanks David